# Passing PHP function as a value input field

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

I have this problem, my actual code looks like this

```
   <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
             <h4 class="text-center">VOTA!</h4>
                 <!-- empieza star encuesta -->
                 <input value="<?= getRatingByProductId(connect(), 1); ?>"
                       type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.1 data-size="md"
                       data-stars="5" productId=1>
                 <b><label id="ejecutivo" style="color:#1658a2"></label></b>
```

But wen I put the code on my AWS server the code only show like this, don't show the function and shows baadly. Even worst the code does not show entirely. just stop here.

```
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                            <h4 class="text-center">VOTA!</h4>
                            <!-- empieza star encuesta -->
                            <input value="
```

I know it's something wrong on php on this server, but I repeat only happens on the AWS server, on the local server works perfectly.

The PHP code is:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
 return $mysqli;
}

function getRatingByProductId($con, $productId)
{
    $resultado = $con->query("SELECT SUM(vote) as vote, COUNT(vote) as count 
from rating2 WHERE product_id = $productId and nombre='" . $ipaddress . "'");
    $resultSet = $resultado->fetch_assoc();


if($resultSet['count']>0) {
      return ($resultSet['vote']/$resultSet['count']);
} else {
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think during invokation of `<?= getRatingByProductId(connect(), 1); ?>` an error raised on server side.

Comment: on the server side? like, the php does not get the value?

Comment: may be php short tag issue, try to use `<?php echo  getRatingByProductId(connect(), 1); ?>`

Comment: @Bhaskar This is not a short tag issue, php echo tags are valid even when short tags aren't, and are preferred in some instances when the intention is just to echo a value.

Comment: JUST FOR THE RECORD, PHP7 + APACHE2 + MYSQL5.7, read php connection manual too, it's important some things are not available any more. only pdo and mysqli types works now, the mysql type is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is not a Javascript function issue, as the function is PHP-based only. As @reporter states in comments, it looks like something in the echo tag construct is causing an error. I'd suggest:

- Looking at your web server's error log
- Verifying the `mysqli` extension is loaded on the AWS instance
- Verifying that you're using the correct DB credentials for your AWS instance
- Verifying that you can connect to the DB from the AWS instance

Comment: on AWS you can install MYSQL and use it inside the server. is for a small app.. the connection string was the problem. thank you for your response.